# why this java code didn't work?

Tags: java

I trying to learn java. and i was trying to make a program that displays all text from an txt file and it stops when it read a specific number but it didn't work and i don't know what is going wrong.

This is what I have right now:

```
package textLezer;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FileData implements Runnable {

public static final int WIDTH = 320;
public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
public static final int SCALE = 3;
public final String NAME = "Text lezer";

public JFrame frame;
public static JLabel label = new JLabel();
public static JPanel panel = new JPanel();

private Thread thread;

public boolean running = false;

public void start() {
    running = true;

    thread = new Thread(this, NAME + "_main");
    thread.start();
}

public void stop() {
    try {
        thread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {
    String file_name = "text/test.txt";
    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
            if (aryLines[i].equals("5")) {
                return;
            } else {
                label.setText("<html>" + label.getText() + " <br> "
                        + aryLines[i] + "</html>");
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

launcher file:

```
package textLezer;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Launcher {

private static FileData data = new FileData();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FileData.panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    FileData.panel.add(FileData.label);

    data.frame = new JFrame();

    data.frame.setTitle(data.NAME);
    data.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    data.frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    data.frame.setSize(800, 400);
    data.frame.add(FileData.panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    data.frame.setResizable(false);
    data.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    data.frame.setVisible(true);

    data.start();
}
}
```

and the txt file:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Comment: you haven't yet say anything bad :)

Comment: "it din't work" doesn't provide enough information. What happened? Can you reduce your code to a shorter example? Do you really need a UI to demonstrate the problem, for example? See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: 1) What does the program do, and what did you expect instead? 2) Tiny detail: use `WIDTH * 9 / 12` instead of `WIDTH / 12 * 9`. You're using integers, and integer division always rounds toward zero. To reduce rounding error, do the multiplication first, and then the division.

Comment: @Rhymoid double-edged sword. Multiplying first has more chance of overflow :)

Comment: @Cruncher: true! That won't happen with numbers this small, though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are using `return;` statement inside for loop. What you actually need here is a `break;` statement

Also the way you create the html for a multiline label is wrong. It wont work because the final html generated would be

```
<html><html><html><html> <br> 1</html> <br> 2</html> <br> 3</html> <br> 4</html>
```

So you should refine your concatenation logic.

```
public void run() {
    String file_name = "text/test.txt";
    try {
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

        StringBuilder innerText = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i++) {
            if (aryLines[i].equals("5")) {
                break;
            } else {
                innerText.append(aryLines[i]).append("<br/>");
            }
        }
        label.setText("<html>" + innerText.toString() + "</html>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```